# Sending a generated value to XML for formatting

Tags: android, xml, int

I would like to begin by saying I don't have the best java knowledge because I'm still learning it in school, but I decided to go off on my own and attempt to create an android application.

Right now, I have my program generating two different random numbers. I'm trying to get these generated ints to be shown in the application. I want it to be done through XML formatting tho because of the control I have over what I want it to look like.
My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to pass the values over to the XML file. I'm not sure if I should be using "android:text" and somehow integrating the name of the ints in that(Which i've attempted.) or what.

I've tried to google for an explanation of what can be done, but I think my lack of ability to really put my issue into words is holding me back.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be using the XML file to set the Text.  You use the xml file to set the look and feel, like this (note the android:id= line):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/randomInt1" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
<TextView android:id="@+id/randomInt1" />
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

then in your java code in onCreate for the activity that will be showing the ints you will do something like this:

```
int random_int1=0;
int random_int2=100;
((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.randomInt1)).setText(random_int1);
((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.randomInt2)).setText(random_int2);
```

Comment: And would I need to add anything to the xml(Such as "android:text" or will it just show up then?

Comment: No, setText in the Java will put the text in the TextView.  No android:text is required.  Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I did, but in the graphical layout preview, it doesn't show any text. And i'm getting this error when trying to run the program in my AVD to see if it will show up there: "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.", so i need to debug my program before I can continue. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: You won't see the text in the graphical layout editor.  You won't see it until you can get the code running since you are changing the text programmatically.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for all the help. I'm just going to go ahead and assume that I typed everything out correctly and that the text will appear when I get my program running xD

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is you need to make a "link" between the java and the xml.

This can be done in java with the following line(quick example I pulled out of my code):

TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

then this can be set using:

nameView.setText(PutStringHere);

This is a fundamental part of android development. It's the link between the java and the xml. You can edit other things though the java TextView.

Comment: What would I put in the XML then to call the newly created text. Would i use "android:text" or something else?

Comment: Look at the code I put in below.  The first part is what you would put in the XML.

Comment: Alright. I wasn't sure if it was supposed to show up in the graphical preview on the xml or not(Which is doesn't). So, i tried running the app on my AVD, but i'm getting this error: "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.", so i need to debug my program before I can continue. Thanks for the help tho.